# C# GDAL DEM Speed

Tags: gdal

My 64-bit, Win 7 C# application using GDAL creates a number of constant-bearing paths with 1000+ points along each path.  At each point, I want to look up the 4 closest elevations for interpolation.  At this point, I'm using USGS 1/3 arcsec FLT data, where files are about 450MB.

My abstraction creates a "catalog" where I can look up the 1 degree square file containing the point, and then I read the 4 closest raster points.  Naively, the first cut just walks down each path in turn.  Average time to process one path is 25 sec on cold start, and 2 sec on warm start (i.e. subsequent runs without unmounting the disk device).  Running the VS 2012 profiler, all my time is spent in GDALRasterBand.RasterIO.

I have tried doing my own simple caching, reading a few adjacent lines so that I am guaranteed to have all 4 points in memory with a single RasterIO call.  It doesn't help.  I tried reading the files into memory, but oddly encountered memory allocation errors somewhere in the midst of the 14+ FLT files.

This is far from ideal performance.  I'm wondering if anyone can offer advice on speeding this up.  Is the .NET interop penalty my problem?  Do I need to sort the points to some order?  Or something smarter?

Thanks for any help.

-reilly.